# Finding Common (or repeated) keys in unsorted_multimap

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

Any idea about how to get common keys from large set of `unsorted_multimap` ??? I use `file_name(string)` as a key and its `size(int)` as a value. Basically I am scanning a directory for searching duplicate files using boost and holding entry of each file in `unsorted_multimap`. Once this map is ready I need to output common keys(file_name) and there sizes as a list of duplicate files.

Comment: Lots of ideas. Sorting them, or using a unique container to track collisions, would be a good start. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

**How to find common keys of an `unsorted_multimap` ?**

The following code searches for a specific filename, and iterates through all elements with the same key:

```
std::unordered_multimap<std::string, int> mymulti;      // key: filename, value: size  
//... fill the multimap
for (auto x = mymulti.find("fileb"); x != mymulti.end() && x->first == "fileb"; x++) { 
    std::cout << x->second << " ";    // do something !
}
std::cout << "}\n";  // end something !
```

**How to iterate through an `unsorted_multimap`, goupring processing by common keys ?**

The following code iterates trhough the whole map, and for eacuh key, processes in a subloop the related values:

```
for (auto i = mymulti.begin(); i != mymulti.end(); ) {  // iterate through multimap
    auto group = i->first;         // start a new group
    std::cout << group << "={";    // start doing something for the group
    do {                    
        std::cout << i->second << " ";  // do something for every values of the group
    } while (++i != mymulti.end() && i->first == group);  // until we change value
    std::cout << "}\n";                 // end something for the group 
}
// end overal processing of the map
```

**How to find duplicate files (same key and same value ) ?**

Using the building blocks above, you could for every filename, you could create a temporary unsorted_map with the size as value, looking if the element is already in the temporary map (duplicate) or adding it (non duplicate).

If the whole purpose of your `unsorted_multimap`is to process these duplicates, then it would be pbetter, from the start to build an  `unosorted_map` with filenames as keys, and value a `multimap` with size as sorted key and values, the other elements you collect on the file (full url ? inode ? wathever):

```
unsorted_map<string, multimap<long, filedata>> myspecialmap;
```